# javascript clear asp textbox on html button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to clear an asp textbox when click to a button (html).

so basically the JS function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearTextBox() {
        document.getElementByID('<%=txtFName.ClientID%>').value = "";
    }
</script>
```

And an asp.net TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="30" />
```

And a HTML button

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn default" id="clearButton" type="button" onclick="clearTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</span>
```

All buttons and other controls are in an asp update-panel (don't know if it makes different)

Nothing happend when I clicked to the HTML clearButton, error on the web console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
clearTextBox 
onclick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementByID
```

to

```
document.getElementById
```

and it worked. Credit goes to [Mudassar](http://www.aspforums.net/Users/Mudassar/Profile/)

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass Id of textbox, in your case it should be:

```
document.getElementByID('txtFName').value = "";
```

and then assign method to you input something like this

```
asp:textbox ..... onClick="yourMethodName"
```

Comment: tried `document.getElementByID('txtFName').value = "";` but same error

Comment: i have one more idea. Try to change method inside you textbox OnClick to OnClientClick=("YourJavaScriptMethodName")

Answer (score 2):

Move your following js code in page header or some other place, right now it is unable to find your js function. It must be breaking due to some error or break. Or try to put js alert/debugger in your js function to make sure that are you even able to find this function. Clearing the textbox is next step.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearTextBox() {
    alert('Hello World');
}</script>
```

Now, if you are able to see your alert then your code can find your function. Then modify your textbox tag like:

```
<asp:TextBox CliendIDMode="Static" ID="txtFName" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="30" />
```

Now, modify your clearTextBox function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearTextBox() {
    document.getElementById('txtFName').value = '';
}</script>
```

Comment: the alert worked but when change to `document.getElementById('txtFName').value = '';` it showed same error

Comment: open the browser console and type $('input'), now check can you see your textbox 'txtFName' in this list, try to find its exact client-side id

Comment: yes I can see it, it looks as: `<input name="txtFName" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30" id="txtFName" cliendidmode="Static" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">`

Comment: so type document.getElementById('txtFName').value = '' in console, if it is working in console, it should be in JS as well

Comment: yes typed `document.getElementById('txtFName').value = 1000` and it workes, textbox showed 1000, but still same error when I clicked to the button

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest add JS into `Head part of page.` then it will not create the `Uncaught ReferenceError: clearTextBox is not defined`

Comment: I put it on `<head>` but still same problem, in fact if I put other JS and Jquery on the head it will cause a lot of problem unless I move them under body tag

Comment: I click "View page source" and see all, JS and all control codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

so you text box will look like this

```
<asp:TextBox CliendIDMode="Static" ID="txtFName" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="30" />
```

In asp.net when page renders the id of controls changes

I suggest you should use jquery.

```
$("#txtFName").val("");
```

Also return false in your javascript function

Also try in one  block your JS

Comment: can you post full jquery function and how to call it on the control, my JS and JQuery is weak

Comment: @RonaldinhoState If you are using VS 2010. Jquery is included in website project. Just drag 3 jquery files from script folder and drop it on your page's header section and use the line of code I wrote above

Comment: @RonaldinhoState Updated my answer should return false on your javascript function

Comment: I think I have Jquery references included, I still having hard time to figure out how to follow your answer, have no idea about how to use JS and Jquery.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState post ur html in question I think u r writng ur JS code not correctly

Comment: added my .aspx code, the `<form>` is so long so I cut them off, basically the Textbox and the button are inside that form tag (also inside a UpdatePanel)

Comment: @RonaldinhoState why don't you have just one <script> inline JS block instead of multiple?

Comment: will it make any different? I put them in separate block to easy for edit and copy/paste to other places.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearTextBox() {
   var elements = [] ;
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control"); // your class name 

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){
       elements[i].value = "" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have more than one control using `form-control` CSS class, how do I do?